# generalized Noether-Lefschetz Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have always had problems in understanding what people mean when they say "the generalized Theorem of ...". For instance, I seem to understand that there are a few different *generazlized* Noether-Lefschetz theorems. Can someone list the different versions?

Comment: The set of smooth projective K3 surfaces with Picard number $\rho$ has codimension $\rho−1$ in the moduli space.

Comment: One generalization is to allow singularities. I believe that 
Srinivas and Ravindra wrote a paper generalizing the theorem to normal 3 folds.  